# hide clone post in index view blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a clone function in my livewire show blade , so when a user clone the post , I don't want the clone post to show in the general post view blade

```
Post::get();
```

view blade

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
``
 (
```

I won't like to have same post in the index

I only want to display the user clone post in there profile

how can I do this
livewire components

```php
public function clone($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $newPost = $post->replicate();
    $newPost->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $newPost->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to identify if a post was cloned or not. To achieve this, you can add a field `cloned_post_id` to your `posts` table, then when you clone it, set the ID from the originating post.

Once you have this data, you can filter out the cloned posts in your register - the best way to achieve this is by adding a relation on the Post model, and check that it does not exist - but you can also check `whereNull('cloned_post_id')`.

Clone the post,

```php
public function clone($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $newPost = $post->replicate();
    $newPost->cloned_post_id = $post->id;
    $newPost->updated_at = Carbon::now();
    $newPost->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $newPost->save();
}
```

Then in your Post model, add that relation,

```php
public function clonedPost() 
{
    $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'cloned_post_id');
}
```

Then in your register, check `whereDoesntHave()`, to exclude the posts that was cloned,

```php
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave('clonedPost')->get();
```